# How do I fire up CellContentDoubleClick in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using VS 2010 C#.

I have a form that only has a grid connected to a table. Basically, my idea is to select a row by double clicking it. Then later copy the ID and close the form to proceed to another form. But it is not working as per my test on doubleclick event on grid. It is suppose to show a Message box but it is not triggering.

I'm still new on C# and I've browsed the net for similar problem but most of the example are in VB, there was even one suggestion for me to make dgv a readonly=false (implemented on code).

Here is my code:

```
    ...

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'cISDataSet.tbl_Person' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.tbl_PersonTableAdapter.Fill(this.cISDataSet.tbl_Person);
        this.dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;
    }

    private void DataGridView1_CellContentDoubleClick(Object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        MessageBox.Show("test");
    }  

    ...
```

I do not have any syntax error on my program.

Comment: Are you using Winform or WPF ???

Comment: I'm using Winform sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line to your form1_load.  (after `this.dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;`)

```
dataGridView1.CellContentDoubleClick += DataGridView1_CellContentDoubleClick;
```

You only need to tell the data grid view where to go when a double click happens.